# Custom field publish for users collection is not working properly

Tags: meteor

I just added one custom field into default users table. we do publish the specific field and subscribed. when we tried to access the particular field value in the account methods "Accounts.onLogin" it has value on initial login but it lost on reactive refresh.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) { 
  Meteor.publish("users",function(){
     return Meteor.users.find({_id:this.userId},{fields:{"customField":1}}); // Publish the user with custom fields
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
   Meteor.subscribe("users");
   Accounts.onLogin(function(){
     alert(Meteor.user().customField + ' Comes '); // it has value on initial login but it lost on reactive refresh.
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can only extend `profile` in Meteor.users.. See this discussion for more: https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-add-new-field-on-meteor-users/1065/2

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Appreciate your reply.I can't vote because still i am not eligible.